# Node + usb - No native build for platform=win32 arch=x64

Tags: node.js

trying to create a simple node app using usb package.

pkg dist/main.js

I'm getting this error.  Any idea on how to solve it?
node version = 16.16.0

```
    package.json
    "assets": [
        "node_modules/usb/prebuilds/*"
      ],
    
Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=93 uv=1 libc=glibc node=16.16.0
    loaded from: C:\snapshot\printserver\node_modules\usb

    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\printserver\node_modules\node-gyp-build\node-gyp-build.js:60:9)
    at load (C:\snapshot\printserver\node_modules\node-gyp-build\node-gyp-build.js:22:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\printserver\node_modules\usb\dist\usb\bindings.js:8:38)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1930:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1855:31)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```